# grts() spsurvey error: dims [product 16] do not match the length of object [17]

Tags: r, spatial

I am using grts() function in spsurvey

```
unique(shape$strataFACT2)
 [1] "thirty-four"  "twenty-three" "thirty-three"
 [4] "twenty-four"  "twelve"       "thirty-two"  
 [7] "fourteen"     "thirty-one"   "twenty-two"  
[10] "twenty-one"   "forty-two"    "fifty-one"   
[13] "forty-one"    "fifty-two"    "thirteen"    
[16] "forty-three"  "fifty-four"  



caty_n=c("twelve"=1,"thirteen"=1,"fourteen"=1,
         "twenty-one"=1,"twenty-two"=1,"twenty-three"=3,
         "twenty-four"=2,
         "thirty-one"=2,"thirty-two"=2,"thirty-three"=4,
         "thirty-four"=2,
         "forty-one"=1,"forty-two"=1,"forty-three"=1,
         "fifty-one"=1,"fifty-two"=2,"fifty-four"=1)
length(caty_n)

sum(caty_n)


strat_propprob <- grts(shape2, 
                     n_base = sum(caty_n), 
                     caty_var = "strataFACT2",
                     caty_n=caty_n)
```

I have now run this code multiple times in other scripts with no issue. However, I am now getting the error:

```
Error in grtspts_ip(type = dsgn[["seltype"]][stratum], n_base = n_caty,  : 
  dims [product 16] do not match the length of object [17]
In addition: Warning message:
In n_base/gsum[catmatch] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I don't understand how this error is relevant because my caty_n object length is indeed 17.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that depending on the seed set, grts() would not choose all of the categories available. I had to keep changing the seed until it actually executed without error.